# How to Show and Update hidden div element by hovering on one of three buttons in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, dynamic

I want to hover over on the buttons and want to show a hidden div/panel underneath it by using java script. My Javascript is externally included and works fine, i am trying to use the DOM model to change the style and innerHTML of the div but isnt working. This is my HTML, Javascript and CSS code below. I am even passing parameters to verify which button was hovered but failing.
HTML

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row anchorbutton">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <a href=#><div class=" mainbuttons b1 text-center"  
         onmouseover="updatepanel(1);" onmouseout="hidepanel()">Workout 
                                    Programs</div></a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
          <a href=#><div class=" mainbuttons b2 text-center" 
             onmouseover="updatepanel(2);" onmouseout="hidepanel()"> Diet 
               Plans</div></a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 ">
           <a href=#><div class=" mainbuttons  b3 text-center" 
            onmouseover="updatepanel(3);" onmouseout="hidepanel()"> Food 
             Supplements</div></a>
     </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="panel panel-default hidden">
       <div class="hoverable panel-body hidden"> </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

JS

```
function hidepanel(){

var panel=document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
panel.style.display=none;
}

 function updatepanel(x){
 var desc1="Get fully customized workout programs from our dedicated fitness 
 experts.";
 var desc2="Nutrional advice and diet plans just for your needs!";
 var desc3="Our very own state-of-the-art line of supplementations.Click to 
 Order";

  if(x==1){}
  document.getElementsByClassName('hidden').style.display='block';
  document.getElementsByClassName('hidden').innerHTML='desc1';
  }
   if(x==2){
   document.getElementsByClassName('hidden').style.display='block';
   document.getElementsByClassName('hidden').innerHTML='desc2';
   }
    if(x==3){
     document.getElementsByClassName('hidden').style.display='block';
      document.getElementsByClassName('hidden').innerHTML='desc3';
       }
   }
```

CSS

```
.hidden{
 display: none;
 }
```

I have also tried to change the functionality by changing the function to work on onClick instead of onmousehover but it wont work.Please help me out i have been banging my head.

Answer (score 4):

[`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [`HTML Collection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which is a collection of elements, so saying things like `collection.style.display` or `collection.innerHTML` doesn't make a whole lot of sense. I think what you are wanting to do is grab the individual element and update the properties, like so:

`document.getElementsByClassName("hidden")[0]`.

If you need to iterate over the collection, you can access a `length` property and do a traditional `for` loop, or you can do an `Array.from()` using ES6.

```js
function hidepanel() {
  var panel = document.querySelector(".hidden");
  panel.style.display = "none";
}

function updatepanel(x) {
  var desc1 = "Get fully customized workout programs from our dedicated fitness experts.";
  var desc2 = "Nutrional advice and diet plans just for your needs!";
  var desc3 = "Our very own state-of-the-art line of supplementations.Click to Order";
  
  // make variable so we don't have to search the DOM 2 times for every panel
  var hiddenElem = document.querySelector(".hidden"); 
  var panelBody = document.querySelector(".panel-body");
  if (x == 1) {
    hiddenElem.style.display = 'block'; 
    panelBody.innerHTML = 'desc1';
  }
  // don't evaluate unnecessarily
  else if (x == 2) {
    hiddenElem.style.display = 'block'; 
    panelBody.innerHTML = 'desc2';
  }
  // don't evaluate unnecessarily
  else if (x == 3) {
    hiddenElem.style.display = 'block'; 
    panelBody.innerHTML = 'desc3';
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row anchorbutton">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <a href=#>
        <div class=" mainbuttons b1 text-center" onmouseover="updatepanel(1);" onmouseout="hidepanel()">Workout Programs
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
      <a href=#>
        <div class=" mainbuttons b2 text-center" onmouseover="updatepanel(2);" onmouseout="hidepanel()"> Diet Plans
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 ">
      <a href=#>
        <div class=" mainbuttons  b3 text-center" onmouseover="updatepanel(3);" onmouseout="hidepanel()"> Food Supplements
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default hidden">
    <div class="hoverable panel-body"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use the built in [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), which returns a `NodeList`, which *does* have a built in iterator function (`forEach`), which makes iterating over the list cleaner/easier.

That would look like so:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".hidden").forEach(function (elem) {
  elem.syle.display = "block";
  // etc...
});
```

Comment: This just saved my project, cheers. So you have used document.getElementsByClassName("hidden")[0] so the innermost div is updated and accessed right?

Comment: @TayyabNaveed `[0]` will grab the **first** element in the collection. The DOM is traversed hierarchically, so that will actually be the outer hidden div, not the innermost one. If you want the innermost one, what I would recommend is that you remove the `.hidden` class from the innermost one, use `.panel-body` as your selector for when you update the `innerHTML` and only show/hide the parent. If an element's parent is hidden, it is also hidden - double hiding/showing is unnecessarily redundant

Comment: @TayyabNaveed I have updated the code in my post to reflect my above comment

Answer (score 0):

First `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an HTML Collection so you must specify the index of the element you want to use, like: `document.getElementsByClassName('hidden')[0]`.

Second `panel.style.display` must be a defined as a string, so change `none` to `"none"` in your hide function

Working codepen: https://codepen.io/sunrisem/pen/QagPLG

Comment: It doesn't return an array, it returns a live HTML Collection. Two *very* different data structures

Answer (score 0):

Don't use inline javascript in your html, instead loop the elements and attach an event listener to them. You can set data-attributes on the button, so you could either create an array like shown below holding the texts, or you could put the text as a data-attribute. You'll also need a listener that reacts on the mouse leaving the button, to hide the div again. You should be easily able to change the code to fit your classes...

```js
let div = document.getElementById('d');
let descriptions = [
  "Get fully customized workout programs from our dedicated fitness experts.",
  "Nutrional advice and diet plans just for your needs!",
  "Our very own state-of-the-art line of supplementations.Click to Order"
];

document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('mouseover', ({
    target
  }) => {
    div.innerHTML = descriptions[target.getAttribute('data-nr')];
    div.classList.remove('hidden');
  }, false);
  e.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    d.classList.add('hidden');
  }, false)
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

div {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" data-nr="0">
1
</button>
<button class="btn" data-nr="1">
2
</button>
<button class="btn" data-nr="2">
3
</button>
<div id="d" class="hidden">

</div>
```

Comment: ES6 functions, data-* attributes, event listeners, object destructuring with no explanation... Probably less than useful for the OP who is clearly a novice with JS